# Gitlab : How to batch modify the visibility of projects and groups on GitLab 11.x?

Tags: gitlab, batch-processing

I had to change the visibility of many projects and groups in my Gitlab. Because it doesn't have this kind of feature on my version (11.x), I had to do it another way.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by using JS :

To change visibility of "Internal" Projects to "Private", I run this JS script from my browser console on "Internal" projects list page (/explore/projects?sort=latest_activity_desc&visibility_level=10) :

```
jQuery("A.project").each(function () {
  let that = jQuery(this);
  let href = that.attr("href");

  jQuery.ajax(href+"/edit").done(function (data) {
    let rx = /authenticity_token\" value=\"([^"]*)/gm;
    let authArr = data.match(rx);
    let auth = rx.exec(authArr[1]);

    console.log(authArr);
    console.log(auth);

    jQuery.ajax(href, {method: "POST", data: "utf8=%E2%9C%93&_method=patch&update_section=js-shared-permissions&project%5Bvisibility_level%5D=0&commit=Save+changes&authenticity_token="+auth[1]});
  });
})
```

I did the same from groups list page for groups (/admin/groups) :

```
jQuery(".fa-shield").each(function () {
jQuery("A.btn[href*=edit]", jQuery(this).closest(".group-row")).each(function () {
  let that = jQuery(this);
  let href = that.attr("href");

  jQuery.ajax(href).done(function (data) {
    let rxAuth = /authenticity_token\" value=\"([^"]*)/gm;
    let auth = rxAuth.exec(data);

    console.log(auth);


    let rxId = /group_id\"[^>]+value=\"([^"]*)/gm;
    let id = rxId.exec(data);

    console.log(id);

    jQuery.ajax(href, {method: "POST", data: "utf8=%E2%9C%93&_method=patch&group%5Bvisibility_level%5D=0&authenticity_token="+auth[1]+"group_id="+id[1]});
  });

});
})
```

Sorry for ugly code, I did it quickly and doesn't have much time to share it.